# How to obtain 'lookup key" in Android Contacts API?

Tags: android, android-contacts

Following is from Android Documentation

> You can acquire a lookup key from the contact itself, it is a column
>   on the ContactsContract.Contacts table.

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey)

Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[]{Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},        ...);
try {
c.moveToFirst();
String displayName = c.getString(0);
} finally {
c.close();
}
```

but couldn't get it to work.

I visited answers on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754217/android-manage-contacts-with-lookup-key) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940864/android-manage-contacts-with-lookup-key) but in vein.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the documentation is related to how to use the *lookupKey* once you get it, not how to obtain it.

Like they said, you can acquire it from the Contacts table. So, in order to get the *lookupKey* for each contact in your contacts list, you can use the following projection (the rest of the code provided is only here to show the results, you can use it as you want):

```
String [] PROJECTION = new String [] {  ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY };

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);


for(cursor.moveToFirst(); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()) {
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "lookupKey for contact:  " + cursor.getString(1) + ", is: " + cursor.getString(0));
}
```

Comment: Something wrong with my answer? Always glad to learn new things, but please when you down vote, explain why?! Because I really think this is a good answer to his question since it does provide lookup keys for each contact (I have written the code and tested it).

Comment: I dont know who downvoted it, I am still trying to understand you answer, once I am done I will comment.

Comment: Each contact has a `lookupKey`. The code shown in my answer helps you get that `lookupKey` for each one of them. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanations if it's unclear.

Comment: Android Documentation says **If you need to read an individual contact, consider using CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI instead of CONTENT_URI.** [link]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html But in your answer we are infact using CONTENT_URI to obtain the Display Name.

Comment: I think lookupkey in only for one contact. Android documentation "If you need to read an **individual contact**, consider using CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI instead of CONTENT_URI.

Comment: Can we register ContentObserver for single contact entry ? I tried it but in onChange() method, i'm not getting the Uri of the changed contact, so that i can query that particular contact.