# Which one is better in _ID and LOOKUP_KEY and the reason

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I want to search the contact list to get a particular contact using _ID or LOOKUP_KEY. Which one of these two is better and the reason. It will be really helpful if you give the main differences of both.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#LOOKUP_KEY check this out

Answer (score 0):

[Android Doc says-](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html)

1. _ID - Row ID. Consider using LOOKUP_KEY instead.
2. LOOKUP_KEY - An opaque value that contains hints on how to find the contact if its **row id changed** as a result of a sync or aggregation.

So when in case the contacts RowID change for any reason LOOKUP_KEY is our way to go. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554743/how-to-obtain-lookup-key-in-android-contacts-api) on how to find it as this is not there on Docs I guess.