# Android Contacts API - Does Lookup Key still change in Android 5.1+?

Tags: android, sql, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

[This question from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754217/android-manage-contacts-with-lookup-key) asks if you can manage contacts using the Lookup Key. According to the [Official Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider#ContactBasics), the Lookup Key is meant to be a permanent link to the contact. But, an answer to the question says that **it is possible that the Lookup Key may change**.

That was Android 2.x Days...

> Does this fact still remain true? Does the Lookup Key still change or
>   can I reliably use it as a link to a contact regardless of aggregation
>   and sync operations now? (My `minSdkVersion` is 22 - Android 5.1 Lollipop and above)

I'm asking because I want to store the Lookup Key in the database and exclude those specific contacts the next time I run through the Contacts List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the lookup key does still change. You're better off saving a custom value and seeing if that specific value exists next time.